# foreground service notification buttons working weirdly on Restart of the Activity(which was bound to service)

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a `MusicPlayerActivity` (its launchMode is SingleTop in the Manifest) and `MainActivity`, both bound to a `MusicService`. Everything seemed fine, but then I saw a bug: there is no problem in playing the first song. But when I play the second song, and try to use notification's buttons to control it, the behave as if pressed twice. So, a pause would result into a play again and next would result in skipping one song.

**What I tried:**-I thought that it was due to using a combination of `startForeground()` and `NotificationManager`, so I removed all the `NotificationManager` part and started using `startForeground`, even for updating the notifications (I hope this is not a wrong practice). But it didn't work.

**What I think the problem is:**
I'm not certain, but I think the problem lies in creating the new instance of `MusicPlayerActivity`. For first song, it is okay and bound, then `onBackPressed()`, `MainActivity` is `MovedToFront`. Then when the user selects another song from this `MainActivity`, a new instance of `MusicPlayerActivity`is created and **bound** with the service again. The songs play fine but notifications starts being weird.

**This is how I create notification in `playSong()` method of `Service`**:

```
void playSong(){
...

            setNotification(songTitle);
}
public void setNotification(String songName) {
        notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_mediacontroller);
        notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, songName);
        setNotificationArt(notificationView);
    notification.contentView = notificationView;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("dummy");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.textView1, pendingNotificationIntent);
        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgAppIc, pendingNotificationIntent);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.flags |= Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;//Dont know why using this flag.
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent switchIntent = new Intent("com.dmmet.musicplayer.ACTION_PLAY");
        PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay2, pendingSwitchIntent);
        Intent closeIntent = new Intent("com.dmmet.musicplayer.ACTION_CLOSE");
        PendingIntent pendingCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnClose, pendingCloseIntent);
        Intent nextIntent = new Intent("com.dmmet.musicplayer.ACTION_NEXT");
        PendingIntent pendingNextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, nextIntent, 0);

        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext, pendingNextIntent);
        Intent previousIntent = new Intent("com.dmmet.musicplayer.ACTION_PREVIOUS");
        PendingIntent pendingPreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, previousIntent, 0);

        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, pendingPreviousIntent);

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

**This is how I bind `MusicPlayerActivity` to the Service:**

```
 public ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder)service;

            //get service
            musicService = binder.getService();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //pass list
            //musicService.setList(Q1);
            musicBound = true;
            if(musicBound){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ready to play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                musicService.queue(Q1,start);
                //musicService.playSongContinuation(Q1.get(start));
            }
            Log.d("ServiceConnection","connected");

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d("ServiceConnection","disconnected");
            musicBound = false;
        }

    };



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(intent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

Comment: can you please show code related two things
1) How you creating the notifications ?
2) Code of you MusicPlayerActivity and how you bind the service ?

Comment: Yes sure. I added the code.

Comment: isnt it creating another instance of service ?

Comment: Your service is oneShot?

Comment: no it's not oneShot

Comment: i think it is creating anogther instance of service , can you test this ?

Comment: I don't think so. I have a boolean musicBound which I pass and retrieve through Bundle. So, the activity binds to service only once in onStart() because I use: `if(!musicBound){ bindService(intent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);}`. I think it has something to do with new instance of activity being created and then something happens. I cannot figure out what!